# WCF-MSMQ Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, msmq

Can we use the public queues without the Windows domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential difference between public and private queues in MSMQ is that public queues are published in Active Directory (and all that entails). So to answer your question, no you cannot (though without much context in your question, perhaps I am missing something).

That said private queues are plenty capable (plus they are not subject to the dependency and performance hit of public queues) and they may be accessed across different machines (I think the `private` moniker can be a little misleading). By using the Direct Format Name, you may access an MSMQ on another machine via a computer address (be that a local computer name, an IP address, etc). Here is a useful article describing some of the differences between the public and private queues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346%28WS.10%29.aspx

And here is a useful article on using MSMQ in the enterprise.

http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/22314

Comment: Agreed with you .Thanks for the explanation.